# include own html and css in outlook signature

Tags: html, css, outlook

**EDIT**
I have implemented the html as a signature, but the problem  im having now is very weird.

I have a signature and everytime i send it from outlook to a web mail service outlook put tags in the html and messes up all the spacing. How can i fix that.

*I have a question about the Outlook signature. For my work I have to make a signature so it looks more professional. I've made a test to see how I need to implement it into the HTML of the signature, but I can't quite figure it out.*

This is the code which Outlook generates:

```
    <style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-520092929 1073786111 9 0 415 0;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
p.MsoAutoSig, li.MsoAutoSig, div.MsoAutoSig
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"E-mailhandtekening Char";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
span.E-mailhandtekeningChar
    {mso-style-name:"E-mailhandtekening Char";
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:E-mailhandtekening;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    mso-default-props:yes;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:595.3pt 841.9pt;
    margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;
    mso-header-margin:35.4pt;
    mso-footer-margin:35.4pt;
    mso-paper-source:0;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>


</head>

<body lang=NL style='tab-interval:35.4pt'>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoAutoSig><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-theme-font:
minor-latin'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I really don't understand where I need to put in my code. 
This is my code:

```
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
    width:50%;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.topText {
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.topLine {
   border-top: 2px solid  #C80032;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content {
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

p {
    font-size:10pt;
}

.left-content {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 140px;
}

.right-content {
}

.name {
    margin: 0px !important;
    float: left;
}

.address {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.address_A {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.address_M {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 14px;
}

.bottomBar {
    float: right;
    width:74.5%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color:#7F7B7B;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 18px;
}

.tableStyle{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.social-Blocks
{
    background-color:white;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 25px !important;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #0987B2;
}

.bottom-bar-first{
    float: left;
    width:11%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color:#7F7B7B;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.bottom_Span{
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.suplaconLogo{
    height:90px ;
    width:190px;
}

.logo{
    float: right;
}


</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="topText">Met vriendelijke groet,</div>
    <div class="topLine"></div>
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" height="80" width="350">
    <table class="tableStyle" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td><span><strong>Information</strong></span></td><td><span class="address_A"><strong>Information</strong></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="name">T</span><span class="address"> Information</span></td>
            <td><span class="address_A">Information</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><span class="name">M</span><span class="address_M">Information</span></td>
            <td><span class="address_A">Information</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><span class="name">E</span><span class="address">Information </span></td>
            <td><span class="address_A"><a href="">Information</a></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <div class="bottomStyle">
        <div class="bottom-bar-first"></div>
        <div class="social-Blocks"><a href="
"><span class="icon-linkedin center" target="blank"></span></a></div>
        <div class="social-Blocks"><a href="" target="blank"><span class="icon-facebook2 center"></span></a></div>
        <div class="social-Blocks"><a href="" target="blank"><img src="" height="25"></a></div>
        <div class="bottomBar"><span class="bottom_Span"><strong> Information</strong></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I include my code in the code of Outlook, or where do I need to put my code? I found this, and it seems that my CSS is indeed compatible:

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> linking to an external stylesheet is not supported by almost all email clients (for sure Outlook doesn't support it).

so I suggest you put everything in the `head > style` tag

Comment: in your source missing opening `head` , otherwise re-post complete source example mail

Answer (score 1):

My best practice (even if it sounds gross) with Outlook signatures is to style the signature in MS Word and paste this block of text to the Outlook signature box in the options.

I would avoid using own custom css in Outlook.

Comment: Have you tried my approach? With tables in Word you can create your signature just as you want it. Then copy it to Outlook and let Outlook do the magic. At least I would try this.

Comment: Yes it still does the same with the padding and stuff, outlook ads it when you save the signature

Comment: The style thats added is in the question

Comment: Just to be sure: you have **not** used any css in your Word signature? And it does not look like you expect it in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

1. Bring all your styles inline, this should solve the majority of your problems e.g:

> <div class="wrapper" style="width:50%; font-family: Calibri, Candara,
>   Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif;">

2. Include your code in a HTML file
3. Open said HTML file in a browser
4. Highlight and copy the outputted signature to your clipboard
5. Google how to add a signature for your version of Outlook on your OS (eg. [Outlook 2010 Windows](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-and-add-an-email-message-signature-95cce669-d370-43fe-afbe-4e79361dfc12))
6. Paste into the signature field
7. Done. You should have a cross-client signature worthy of acclaim

On a side note I'd recommend not copying and pasting from Word if you can help it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, Outlook sucks. It just doesn't support a lot of CSS. And whether it's the desktop client or webmail version, or even hotmail or msn mail, you'll get different results for each.

This link provides some insight into what is/isn't supported. For example, you cannot float in Outlook.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

You should also be using inline styles as opposed to linking externally or even including a style block in the head so they are not stripped. Here's a tool that will do that automatically.

http://inliner.cm/

Basically, you need to dumb it down for Microsoft because of the lack of CSS support.